# where in an angular app is a good place to store "shared" data

Tags: angularjs, separation-of-concerns

This is somewhat a follow up on my "[Is it bad practice for an angular directive to request data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33210331/is-it-bad-practice-for-an-angular-directive-to-request-data)" Q.

My Q Is where would be the appropriate place to keep application data?
for example - information about the current user such as his name and his roles in the app?

differrent areas (on the screen) and components will depend on this data (e.g - side bar will want to know if the *curentUser.isAnAdmin* and a *helloUser* Directive would like to know the *currentUser.name*

Does this mean that the currentUser should be placed on the *$rootScope*? 
and what should be the trigger for retrieving the initial data for the currentUser and for refreshing this information?

I was thinking of having several *ngController*s responsible for setting up this data on the scope of the same html node as that of the ngApp, but found out that it is not possible to have multiple *ngController*s on a single HTML Item.

I am now thinking of having multiple services with methods that get a scope object and assign the data they are responsible to onto that scope.
  It would allow me to separate code for *currentUser* from code for *someOtherSharedAppData* into two different services and call both of them from the applications's main controller thus assiging the data to the scope associated with the top-most element in the app - does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you asked two questions here:

1. Where to store and manipulate data?
2. When and how should I use the $rootScope (compared to $scope)?

**1)**
I will refer to [this article](http://joelhooks.com/blog/2013/04/24/modeling-data-and-state-in-your-angularjs-application/):
Whenever data and methods need to be reusable I would write a service like this for example.

```
angular.module('modelDemo').service("myModel", [function() {
    this.list = [what, ever, items, you, have];

    this.property= null;
    this.setProperty = function(value) {
        this.property= value;
    };
}]);
```

Note, that I'm **not** passing the $scope as you considered. Instead I would inject the service in my controller and bind the $scope variables like this:

```
$scope.list = myModel.list;
```

If you need, you can even bind to the full model

```
$scope.myModel = myModel;
myModel.setPropery(value)
```

Got the idea? This way all model changes will be directly available to the corresponging view

```
{{myModel.property}}
ng-repeat="item in myModel.list"
ng-click="myModel.setProperty(item)"
```

Conclusion: Yes, you should have different services for your user model and your someOtherSharedAppData models.

**2)**
I will refer to this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739084/angularjs-using-rootscope-as-a-data-store?rq=1).
In short: If you have data that should be available in many views, it is OK to bind your (service) model to $rootScope variables. As you can see in the mentioned discussion there are also other opinions but I think the conclusion is: It depends on the structure and needs of your application.

Comment: Yes actually I did just that. i.e. assiging the service singleton to a variable on the $scope and using binding.
Personally - I don't like using $rootScope.